# How to generate data such that an equation needs to hold?

Tags: random-generation, quadratic-form, constraint, geometry

Can I create or generate $\{y_i\}_{i=1}^{4}$ data set such that this equation holds

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{4}\sum_{j=1}^{4}m_{ij}y_{i}y_{j}=6
$$
where
$$
m=\left[ 
\begin{array}{cccc}
13 & 12 & 3 & 5 \\ 
12 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\ 
3 & 1 & 43 & 3 \\ 
5 & 2 & 3 & 21%
\end{array}%
\right] 
$$

If I can do this, can you please tell me how to do it? or give me a reference.

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: If $\mathbf{M}$ was positive definite, the equality $\mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{M}\mathbf{y}=6$ would imply that $\mathbf{y}$ lies on a hyperellipsoid.  But $\mathbf{y}$ appear to have one negative eigenvalue.

Comment: @JarleTufto so if M was positive definite, I can do this? Are you aware of a function or something in matlab, python or R that does this job? Thank you!

Comment: With $\mathbf{M}$ being symmetric with one negative eigenvalue $\mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{M}\mathbf{y}$ describes a saddle-shaped hypersurface and $\mathbf{y}$ lies on a level curve of this hypersurface.  I'm sure some simple linear-algebra trick can be made to generate points on this set.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperboloid may be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only have one equation and 4 unknowns ($y_i, i=1, 2...4$), the system is undetermined. How about the following method?

Randomly pick $y_i, i=1, 2...3$ from some distribution, then solve numerically for $y_4$

The central idea is to reduce the number of unknows to the number of equations you have, in this case one.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo, I meant we have exactly 4.

Comment: I edited my question accordingly, but the main idea holds.